# Concatenating two arrays and sum with keys via Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-collection

I'm having a set of array in something like this format:

```
[
    {"GA_1":"1","GA_2":null,"GA_3":null,"GA_4":null}, 
    {"SA_1":null,"SA_2":"2","SA_3":null,"SA_4":null}, 
    {"RA_1":"1","RA_2":null,"RA_3":null,"RA_4":null}
]
```

I'm storing this in my mysql text column in json_decoded format. I want to call all the eloquent models and merge these arrays with sum of the each keys on object. For example

1st row contains:

```
[
    {"GA_1":"1","GA_2":null,"GA_3":null,"GA_4":null}, 
    {"SA_1":null,"SA_2":"2","SA_3":null,"SA_4":null}, 
    {"RA_1":"1","RA_2":null,"RA_3":null,"RA_4":null}
]
```

2nd row contains:

```
[
    {"GA_1":null,"GA_2":"1","GA_3":"2","GA_4":null}, 
    {"SA_1":"1","SA_2":null,"SA_3":"3","SA_4":null}, 
    {"RA_1":null,"RA_2":"2","RA_3":null,"RA_4":"5"}
]
```

3rd row contains:

```
[
    {"GA_1":"1","GA_2":null,"GA_3":null,"GA_4":null}, 
    {"SA_1":null,"SA_2":"2","SA_3":null,"SA_4":null}, 
    {"RA_1":"1","RA_2":null,"RA_3":null,"RA_4":null}
]
```

so my final output should be:

```
[
    {"GA_1":"2","GA_2":"1","GA_3":"2","GA_4":null}, 
    {"SA_1":"1","SA_2":"4","SA_3":null,"SA_4":null}, 
    {"RA_1":"1","RA_2":"2","RA_3":null,"RA_4":"5"}
]
```

I'm stuck in how can I achieve this:

```
$games = Game::get();

$grid = [];
foreach ($games as $game) {
    $grid[] = collect($game->grid_values);
}

dd(collect('$grid')->flatten());
```

I'm getting this output:

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried something like this:

```
$games = Game::get();

$d = collect($games)->map(function($item) {
    return json_decode($item->grid_values);
})->flatten();

$x = collect([
    [
        'GA_1' => $d->sum('GA_1'),
        'GA_2' => $d->sum('GA_2'),
        'GA_3' => $d->sum('GA_3'),
        'GA_4' => $d->sum('GA_4'),
        'GA_5' => $d->sum('GA_5'),
        'GA_6' => $d->sum('GA_6'),
        'GA_7' => $d->sum('GA_7'),
        'GA_8' => $d->sum('GA_8'),
        'GA_9' => $d->sum('GA_9'),
        'GA_0' => $d->sum('GA_0'),
    ],
    [
        'SA_1' => $d->sum('SA_1'),
        'SA_2' => $d->sum('SA_2'),
        'SA_3' => $d->sum('SA_3'),
        'SA_4' => $d->sum('SA_4'),
        'SA_5' => $d->sum('SA_5'),
        'SA_6' => $d->sum('SA_6'),
        'SA_7' => $d->sum('SA_7'),
        'SA_8' => $d->sum('SA_8'),
        'SA_9' => $d->sum('SA_9'),
        'SA_0' => $d->sum('SA_0'),
    ],
    [
        'RA_1' => $d->sum('RA_1'),
        'RA_2' => $d->sum('RA_2'),
        'RA_3' => $d->sum('RA_3'),
        'RA_4' => $d->sum('RA_4'),
        'RA_5' => $d->sum('RA_5'),
        'RA_6' => $d->sum('RA_6'),
        'RA_7' => $d->sum('RA_7'),
        'RA_8' => $d->sum('RA_8'),
        'RA_9' => $d->sum('RA_9'),
        'RA_0' => $d->sum('RA_0'),
    ],
]);

return response()->json(['data' => $x], 200);
```

And I got expected result, any improvisation please suggest.